# About Sobolev inequalities

Tags: mathematics

i'm interested in the history of the 2 Sobolev Inequalities. The Gagliardo-Nirenberg-Sobolev inequality and Morrey inequality as here [Sobolev inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality#Gagliardo%E2%80%93Nirenberg%E2%80%93Sobolev_inequality)
.

How did these two inequalities arise? What is the context of its emergence? In what year were they discovered?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [About Sobolev Inequalities](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/6781/about-sobolev-inequalities)